# HEVEC/H.265 GPU decoding

Tags: video, cpu, gpu, codec, daum-pot-player

Is possible to decode files with H.265 video format using GPU?

Specs:

- Intel i5-2400
- NVIDIA 970
- Windows 10 Pro

Tried playing test samples (MKV with H.265 codec, 10bit), ~100% CPU usage, lags...

Tried to use PotPlayer & LAV with DXVA2-Native settings (unsuccessful, same CPU usage).

Tried to use GOM player with enabled H/W acceleration (unsuccessful).

Maybe there is something I need to configure? Or it's impossible with my PC configuration? H.264 sample (with same FPS) playing fine - 20% CPU usage.

Comment: Because you did ask about GPU it is worth noting that your graphics card which seems to belong to the Maxwell family doesn't support it either (or has limited support for it). Source: https://developer.nvidia.com/video-encode-decode-gpu-support-matrix
and http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-970/features

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your CPU is too old and does not support H.265 decoding, and it would appear to be the case for your GPU as well, at least for 10-bit "Main10" profile video.

Using [DXVA checker](https://bluesky-soft.com/en/DXVAChecker.html) you will need to be sure you have HEVC decoding, and for your particular file you will need to have the "Main10" profile as it is a 10-bit video file.

[image]

I think you might need to back off in terms of resolution or bit depth on your test video file.

## For the QuickSync decoder in your CPU

From a [Techreport post in 2015](http://techreport.com/news/27677/new-intel-igp-drivers-add-h-265-vp9-hardware-decode-support):

> Intel graphics drivers releases aren't usually very exciting, but this one is worth pointing out. Numbered 15.36.14.4080, this update imbues **Haswell and Broadwell** processors with hardware acceleration support for two next-gen video formats: HEVC, also known as H.265, and Google's VP9.

What this means is that you probably need either a 4th or 5th generation Intel processor for hardware decoding. Your processor is 2nd generation, denoted by the i5-2xxx series processor number.

You are also trying to play HEVC 10-bit video, which is even more demanding.

There is a [Wikipedia page detailing support video codecs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Quick_Sync_Video#Hardware_decoding_and_encoding) and h.265 is listed as Braswell and above, it is likely that this is the manufacturer intended or "supported at release" information rather than including "we fixed it later" support.

For HEVC 10-bit you would need a Kaby Lake processor, an i5-7xxx, to be able to do full hardware decoding. Just normal HEVC (non 10-bit) would be able to be decoded by (some) earlier processors.

Your CPU is a Sandy Bridge CPU and would contain the first generation of Intel hardware video decoding and support will be limited. At the time it was designed h.265 would not have been as common or as necessary to support.

## For your 970 dedicated graphics

From [this Cyberlink forum post](http://forum.cyberlink.com/forum/posts/list/43436.page) it appears that the 960 and 950 Nvidia cards report that they have this profile, but it does not work fully. My suspicion is that the video file is just too large in resolution.

On the 970 the video decoder is slightly older and as such [does not support h.265/HEVC at all](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvidia_PureVideo#The_sixth_generation_PureVideo_HD) while the decoder in the 960 is newer and apparently should support both [Main and Main10 profiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvidia_PureVideo#The_seventh_generation_PureVideo_HD). That you have different support for video decoding within the range could be disappointing.

As a result your system is going to be falling back to full software decoding for these videos and will probably struggle to play them well.

Comment: thanks for explain, I also thought that it was the processor.

Comment: @Inomoz I've added a bit extra as i just noticed you are testing HEVC 10-bit. That is even more demanding and would need the latest generation for full decoding.

Comment: I'm aware of modern processors and hevc. I just thought that it's possible to decode using a bunch of "video player + NVIDIA video card" bypassing the processor

Comment: Sorry, i completely glazed over the dedicated graphics card. While I would be surprised that it doesn't support HEVC, the 10-bit profile is very demanding still and probably only supported on the absolute latest devices. Get a test sample that is not 10-bit and the 970 will probably be fine.

Comment: Yeah, NVIDIA 970 support HEVEC 8-bit H/W acceleration, 10-bit no (not  good, since most of files is in 10 bit color format). Thx again =)

Comment: @Mokubai Big goof in your answer: The hardware acceleration support added in 15.36.14.4080 is for Intel's internal graphics core and is completely irrelevant to the GPU, i.e., if the OP install a video card with H.265 decoding capability, he will get hardware acceleration.

Comment: @FleetCommand I noticed that after and mentioned in the comments above. I (hoped to) update my answer to be relevant to both the CPU and GPU decoders.